# Run query from VB in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vbscript, vba

I'm trying to set the sql code for a query and then run the query from VB. The problem is that when I change the sql dynamically, the VB opens the query but does not refresh it. It still shows results from old sql. If I check the sql, it has changed, and if I then run the query (! button), it runs with the new sql.

I'm doing:

```
Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("temp_query")
qdf.SQL = SQL_query_string
MsgBox (qdf.SQL)
DoCmd.OpenQuery ("temp_query")
```

With `SQL_query_string` containing the new, dynamically generated sql. The message box shows me that I indeed have the new string. And, as I said, I can check it in the query itself, and it has changed, but `DoCmd.OpenQuery("temp_query")` seems to just give the query the focus, not actually running it. What command runs it with the fresh sql?

Comment: If you want to 'permanently' change it, I think you need a `Save` of some sort (sorry, haven't used Access in yeeaaars).  Then, as @paqogomez says, you need to execute the query.

Comment: @Grim You do not need a save, `qdf.SQL = SQL_query_string` is permanent, as long as the SQL is valid.

Comment: Try `DoCmd.Requery` instead of .OpenQuery.  The documentation specifies it refreshes controls to ensure they have the current information, although it's not specific on whether it applies to open query windows.

Comment: @Fionnuala: If you read the question, the query is ALREADY open.  Hence my attempt to help the OP refresh the display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the query is already open, you need to close it and then reopen, interestingly enough, you probably do not even need to check if it is open, you can just close and then run the code.

```
DoCmd.Close acQuery, "temp_query"
Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("temp_query")
qdf.SQL = SQL_query_string
'MsgBox (qdf.SQL)
DoCmd.OpenQuery "temp_query"
```

Make sure you have not used Set Warnings or On Error resume next, because they will mask errors.